# terraform create map of AZ id to name

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have several subnets, and I am tring to deploy an AWS Glue connection in a specific availability zone. To do so I need the name of the az. In my tf I have the zone ids (e.g.  `euc1-az1`) but I need the names `eu-central-1a`.

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}
locals {
  az_id_to_name_map = { for az in  data.aws_availability_zones.available.names : az.zone_id => az.name }
}
```

`az.zone_id` and `az.name` tf complains "Unresolved reference"

I tried something like this, but obviously zone_id and name are not resolvable. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Could you paste the complete block and the error message?

Comment: @Istvan I added more infomration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a mapping between availability zone IDs and their corresponding names in AWS using Terraform. The data "aws_availability_zones" block you have is correct for retrieving availability zone information, but the issue seems to be with referencing the zone_id and name attributes in the locals block.

The correct way to create the mapping using for expressions in Terraform would be as follows:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}

locals {
  az_id_to_name_map = { for az in data.aws_availability_zones.available.names : az => element(data.aws_availability_zones.available.zone_ids, index(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, az)) }
}
```

In the az_id_to_name_map, we are using the for expression to iterate over the availability zone names and create a mapping between the name and the corresponding zone ID. The element function is then used to retrieve the zone ID based on the index of the zone name.

Now, you can use local.az_id_to_name_map in your Terraform code to reference the availability zone names by their IDs. For example:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-xxxxxxxx"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = "your_subnet_id"
  availability_zone = local.az_id_to_name_map["euc1-az1"]
}
```

This way, you can specify the availability zone name using the zone ID in your Terraform code. Adjust the resource type and attributes accordingly based on your use case.

Comment: almost. maybe I have expressed it poorly, but when I use your way I get: `Changes to Outputs:
  + az_id_to_name_map      = {
      + eu-central-1a = "euc1-az2"
      + eu-central-1b = "euc1-az3"
      + eu-central-1c = "euc1-az1"
    }`. but I try to access e.g. "euc1-az1", so I would need the inverse. I think it should be: `az_id_to_name_map = { for az in data.aws_availability_zones.available.zone_ids : az => element(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, index(data.aws_availability_zones.available.zone_ids, az)) }
`. checking now...